# Convex hull in open layers

Tags: openlayers, convex-hull

I am using openlayers. I have a set of geometry points. I want to find the boundary of these geometry points so that I can create a outline.
After searching on the net, I found that this is called as convex hull.
So does openlayers have in-build support for convex hull?

There is a algorithm "Gift wrapping algorithm" which can do this kind of thing. But I am not clear how to do that in openlayers? Do I need to write my own logic for this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am quite sure Openlayers does not have such feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure openlayers has it, but [Andrew's algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) is probably the best choice in terms of ease of implementation and efficiency if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have implemented it using Giftwrap alogorithm.